# Better place to store your favicon files?

Tags: html, favicon

1) I've just done my first favicon files using  [Real Favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). In the faq of that website it says that it is the very best practice to keep the favicons in the root of the website. I did it but now the root folder has 26 new files!!! 

What I will lose if I move the favicon files to a sub-folder? `Ex: /favicon/favicon.ico`

2) I've noticed that different websites use different methods in terms of favicon code. 
Bootstrap, for instance has just these lines of code:

```
<link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/apple-touch-icon.png>

<link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico>
```

Others have plenty of favicons like Wordpress.com:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16 32x32">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16 32x32">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16 32x32">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/favicon-64x64.png" sizes="64x64">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="//s1.wp.com/i/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
```

For a simple website that does not want more than appear in all browsers do I really should use all the files of the second example - WordPress (and that were provided by the favicon generator), or will I get satisfied with the minimal Bootstrap approach?

Comment: if you have favicon.ico in root of your project, browsers will show it. They specificaly look for that file. I think it is overwritten by <link> tags, so you can use another folder to store it..

Comment: So, in that case I could place the favicon.ico into the root and throw the other 25 files to a subfolder (correcting the href value of the link tag for all those different files)?

Comment: yes, or you can ommit favicon.ico in the root and rely only on <link> tags specified ones, it's up to you :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a great help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) By putting the icons in a sub-directory, you get a few minor drawbacks:

- You need to declare `favicon.ico` and `browserconfig.xml` in the HTML. Two lines of code you can skip if the icons are in the root folder, because this is where IE looks by convention.
- [In your logs you will notice 404 with URLs such as `/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-120x120.png`](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/realfavicongenerator/issues/163).
- Yandex search engine displays favicons in its SERP. Apparently it finds them only by looking at the root folder (it doesn't consider the `link` markup). Yandex is used mostly in Russia.

2) You can keep only one Apple Touch icon. It's good enough. Make sure to keep `apple-touch-icon.png` and make it 180x180. [Next release of RealFaviconGenerator will generate only one Touch icon by default](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/realfavicongenerator/issues/211).

Oh, and as the author of RealFaviconGenerator, I congratulate you for your excellent choice ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much:) Perfect answer by the perfect person to answer it:)

Comment: *blush and fly away* :-)

Answer (score 1):

You won't lose anything. So long as you reference the right path in your link tag, all should be well. Also, you don't have to use a .ico. Not many people know this, but you can use other image types so long as you properly reference it in your code.

Comment: My pleasure @viery365 You should note though that the generally accepted format is .ico though. Also, please accept the correct answers for future reference. happy coding :-)